# Curve with one negative and one positive sine-like impulse

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Is it possible to create an algebraic function that is smooth and continuous (i.e., a function in the form $f(x)$ using algebraic functions, with no curly braces that stipulate different behaviour for different domains of $x$, and not piecewise-continuous, smoothly continuous even in the limit) that has the following properties:

**LIST EDITED FOR CLARITY:**

For positive integer $a<b$:

- In the range $x$ equals $-\infty$ to $-b$, the function yields $0$
- In the range $x$ equals $-b$ to $-a$, the function yields a single negative 'pulse' of some form with only one local minimum (an example would be $-\cos\bigl(\frac{1}{b-a}\pi (x+\frac{b-a}{2})\bigr)-1$.)
- In the range $x$ equals $-a$ to $a$, the function yields $0$
- In the range $x$ equals $a$ to $b$, the function yields a single positive 'pulse' of some form with only one local maximum (an example would be $\cos\bigl(\frac{1}{b-a}\pi (x+\frac{b-a}{2})\bigr)+1$.)
- In the range $x$ equals $b$ to $\infty$, the function yields $0$

**END OF EDIT**

The result would be a curve with vaguely sinusoidal behaviour: a single (i.e., non-oscillating) negative pulse between $x=(-b,a)$ and a positive pulse between $x=(a,b)$, and for other values of $x$, the curve either oscillates or flat-lines, but integrates to $0$ across the ranges specified.

I suspect this requires some form of Fourier analysis, and I am sure that the solution will require complex analysis, which is fine.

I understand (to some degree!) complex numbers. But Fourier analysis is something I simply don't know how to do. I just want to find such a curve so I can play with it :-)

**$\color{red}{\text{Edits:}}$**

An example that doesn't quite work is $\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}(\pi (x-n))-\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}(\pi (x+n))$. This creates a curve that could easily be adjusted to create an area of $1$ between points $a$ and $b$ (and the negative equivalent), but it's hard to hit the points $a$ and $b$ precisely (needs to cross $y=0$ at precisely those points), and the integral of the other ranges are not zero.

If the answer is that it's impossible, that's useful info too.

Note that the function should be smoothly continuous, at least in the limit ($\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}$ is an example).

If behaviour is different in the complex plane, that's also fine. So long as it's continuous, and the real part has the behaviour above.

Comment: shouldn't be that somehow like $____/\____$ wave form?

Comment: I was hoping for something that was smooth and continuous - will edit the OP.

Comment: When you write "a single negative pulse between $(-b, a)$, did you mean $(-b, -a)$? And may we assume that $a$ and $b$ are both positive, with $b > a$?

Comment: And does your fifth bullet -- the one about the derivative -- simply mean that $f'(a) =f'(b) = 0$? The use of $x = (a, b)$ is peculiar, as the right hand side typically means either an ordered pair, or an open interval. Perhaps you meant $x \in \{a, b\}$?

Comment: Hi John. I have edited the list of stipulations. Hopefully it is now clearer. Apologies for the messed-up notation; I'm a bit of a newbie.

Comment: Wait...you've completely changed it. It used to say that the *integral* from $b$ to $\infty$ was zero; now you've required that $f(x) = 0$ for $b \le x < \infty$. That latter condition is much, much more restrictive. Are you sure that's what you want? (In the following paragraph, you still say it "integrates to zero across the ranges specified", suggesting that it's *not* what you want.)

Comment: Also: is this really needed only for integer $a$ and $b$ rather than arbitrary positive reals $0 < a < b$?

Comment: You also seem to have lost the condition that $f$ is odd (i.e., that $f(-x) = -f(x)$). Was that intentional?

Comment: In answer: (1) If it integrates to $0$ across those ranges, then that would also work; (2) Doesn't strictly have to be integer, as integer $a$ and $b$ are special cases of arbitrary positive reals, it's just that it was integer values that I was looking at; (3) The stipulation that it be "odd" is equivalent to the edited stipulation of a negative pulse for negative $a$ and $b$ and a positive pulse for positive values. I really appreciate your input, and I apologise for my lack of clarity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just to be clear: 1. if you insist that the function be zero on those ranges, rather than integrating to zero, then there's no hope for it to be as smooth as you're hoping for while still being an "algebraic function"; integrating to zero is comparatively easy. Small changes like this can have a big impact. (b) The "oddness" criterion is far stricter than the "negative/positive pulse" criterion. The negative pulse could be peaked and the positive pulse be relatively flat, for instance, but not if you require oddness. (c) The integer-only  case might be simpler...

Comment: ...than the general case, and if you're only interested in that one, it's generous to let those who are trying to answer it *know* that they only need to address this specific case.

Comment: My apologies again. I had no intention to be obscure or move the goalposts. I am hugely grateful to for everyone's input, and would never presume to expect other people to put in effort on my behalf. In this case, I have been accidentally misleading, and you have borne the brunt of it. In answer: integration to zero is also fine within the given ranges. The 'odd' criterion is that the curve should be anti-symmetric about $x=0$ - a negative mirror image, not two separate types of impulse. I hope this helps. And once again, a huge thank you.

Comment: John, I'm going to mark this as answered because your input has been fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By substitution $x = At + B$, you can shift and compress/expand the location of the bumps in this function to be at any two points you like. The function itself seems as if it captures what you're looking for:

$$
y = \frac{\arctan(t)}{1 + t^2}
$$

Here's a plot via desmos.com:
[image]

====

Oops. Now that I look at your question more clearly, I see that I've produced something more interesting than what you asked for. I'm gonna leave it there anyhow.

There's a small problem because you say that the function should be "odd", but I think that you mean that it should be symmetric (in an "even" sense) around the point $\frac{a+b}{2}$; otherwise most of what you write is inconsistent in the case $a = -1, b = 1$.

The way I derived my example was to take the derivative of $arctan^2(t)$ (and then drop a factor of $2$ to simplify). Starting with arctan-like stuff is generally a good way to work things like this.

But in this case, it's even easier: take a look at the function $y = \frac{sin(x)}{x}$, where you have to define $y = 1$ when $x = 0$; this (or a scaled version of it) is commonly given then name $sinc$, and it has an everywhere convergent power series without any "cases" in it, namely 
$$
sinc(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} + \ldots
$$
This function, or better, 
$$
f(x) = \frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}
$$
has a bump at the origin, and minima at either side of the origin, around $x = \pm 1.43$. Let's call that $x = \pm c$. Then you can arrange, by multiplying by a small constant, to make $\int_{-c}{c} kf(x) dx = 1$. The problem is that the integral over the "tails" won't be $0$. But it'll be pretty close to zero, and you can make a small adjustment to make it work: you just add in a little bit of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. So what I'm claiming is that if you look at 
$$
u(x) = A\left( \frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} + \frac{B}{1+x^2} \right),
$$
you'll have, for $A$ somewhere near $2$, and $B$ around $0.2$, a function that has the properties you want. Using the intermediate value theorem, you can prove that there are values for $A$ and $B$ that achieve your goals (assuming that $a$ and $b$ are approximately $\pm 1.5$). Once you achieve this, you can scale vertically and horizontally to make it work for $a = -1, b = +1$, and then scale and translate to make it work for any $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This looks perfect. I did look at $sinc$ but failed to make it work... Your addition could make all the difference. Let me play with it a little, and then I'll mark as answered. In the meantime, thank you :-)

Comment: OK, I tried this. But it isn't quite what I was looking for. Please see edits to OP. I totally get the idea, but those integer-tolerances are key. I was aware of the sinc function already (even though I don't know how to write it in LaTeX!). It can clearly be laterally and vertically adjusted to create an area of $1$ between $a$ and $b$ (and the same negatively to create area $-1$) - but the area $0->a$ is never going to be $0$... Am I missing something?